# Swift 3 - Access item key values by array index

Tags: swift, nsarray, nsdictionary, plist

Hi im trying to access the items in the legs array inside my plist
I want to be able to get the values for key = "title" from the legs array from this [plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r79k9.png)

I already have the method to get the values from the dictionary called abs which is the following code

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"Exercise", ofType: "plist")

let dict:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)!
if (dict.object(forKey: "levels") != nil) {

    if let levelDict:[String : Any] = dict.object(forKey: "levels") as? [String : Any] {

        for (key, value) in levelDict {

            if ( key == "something") {                    
                     print(value)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However i have no idea how to access the legs array to get item titles

Comment: Would dict["legs"] work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to find an answer to my original question

```
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Exercise", ofType: "plist")
    let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)!
    let levelArray:AnyObject = dict.object(forKey: "legs")! as AnyObject

    if let nsArray:NSArray = levelArray as? NSArray{

        var levelDict:AnyObject = nsArray[1] as AnyObject //currentLevel is an Int

        //then finally I could get data from a dictionary in the array
        let Title = levelDict["title"] as AnyObject? as! String
        print(Title)

    }
```

So now this will print the second item in legs array which is "leg 2"

Answer (score 2):

While reaching to the legs array which is of type `[[String:String]]` in your case with three elements and each index having two key pair values. You can loop over that index and get your values then iterate over to others.

```
let yourLegsArray:AnyObject = dict.object(forKey: "legs")! as AnyObject
```

then iterate over `yourLegsArray` and get the inside values of the `Dict`.

Comment: Great man, do you know how i can show the result in tableview now?

Comment: inside **func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell** . you can use something like this **[ cell.textLabel?.text = the result text which you want to show inside the tableview cells ]** . @IManMerzaie